# How do I keep container or body padding at 5px during resize using bootstrap responsive?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am modifying this layout http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/fluid.html and can't seem to get the container gap/padding to the left, right, and top to stay at 5px during resize. The current padding looks to be around 20px at any screen size.

This gives me what I need until I get to a smaller size. I am not sure at what screen size it changes. It is around the second transition in Chrome. After I get to that small size it reverts back to the larger gap in the example above.

```
body {
  padding-top: 45px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
.cont-pad {
  padding-left:5px;
  padding-right:5px;
}
.container {
  padding-left:5px;
  padding-right:5px;
}
.container-fluid {
   padding-left:5px;
   padding-right:5px;
}
```

I am using this as my html layout that was taken from the example. The colors are to visually see how the containers are padding when resized. One thing I did notice from the modifications I made is the width of the outer most container seems to pad from the side of the browser and not the padding of the div itself once resized. Changing the left and right padding on the body tag changes the padding for my navbar also. Which I don't want.

```
<div class="container-fluid cont-pad" style="background-color:Blue;">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12" style="background-color:Red;">this content should be 5px from left, top, and right</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I assume I need to modify the @media tag in some way. I have tried changing the (max-width: 980px) to 5px but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently building a website using bootstrap responsive 2.3 and I removed the gutter of the page by simply adding this to my CSS.

```
.container-fluid {
padding-right: 0;
padding-left: 0;
}
```

And I've just tried padding-right and left 5px and it seems to work fine.

Are you sure there is no other CSS effecting your containers?

Comment: This works until I resize the page. The first responsive transition drops the top down and the second pushes in the left and right. The thing is the distance in those moves is the same length as the default responsive gap. So it seems that when resizing it is reverting back to the original gap for left, top, and right.

Answer (score 0):

I am struggling with this myself. Bootstrap responsive for smallest size oddly [removes the padding from container-fluid itself](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/responsive-767px-max.less#L21), and then [ADDS padding--of the same amount--to](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/responsive-767px-max.less#L10)  that wasn't there at other sizes.

So you're overwriting the container-fluid padding, but then at small sizes bootstrap sets the container-fluid padding to 0 anyway, and sets other padding on the body (by default, to the exact same size that used to be on the container-fluid, although it's expressed as 20px fixed in one place, and as the $gutterWidth variable in the other. ).

I have no idea why bootstrap does this. It is madness. Bootstrap itself then needs it's own OTHER workarounds to it's own madness -- for instance, media queries on the navbar to compensate and keep the navbar still full-width even at small size.

I am not sure the best way to deal with it for what you want to do, the cleanest, most effective, simplest way. I am in the middle of trying to figure it out myself.

You could try setting the padding on the body at small sizes to what you want, instead of bootstraps.

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {

// Padding to set content in a bit
body {
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

Of course, now the padding is on the body, not the container-fluid, which may do other weird things to your design.  I'm still struggling with this too.

Comment: I have tried everything. I even went through the CSS code and bypassed every @media tag. It seems to always revert back to the 20px size. I even performed a search and changed all 20px parameters in the CSS to 5px and it still does it. I am still looking though.

Comment: Are you looking at the less code, or rendered CSS? It might not be a 20px parameter, it might be a $gutterWidth parameter. You might need to add a class to your